# iOS 5.1 Xcode 5 Child View Controller Orientation did not change

Tags: ios5, xcode5, childviewcontroller

in **iOS5** with **Xcode5** my application support only Landscape orientation when i add child view controller its on portrait and not rotate to landscape mode??

Comment: Add Child view controller in this pattern:

    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    controller.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

its follow the same orientation of parent view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Child view controller in this pattern:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[self addChildViewController:controller];
controller.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
[controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

its follow the same orientation of parent view controller

Comment: Even when using AutoLayout?